# What is the correct way to declare variable type in android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I want to declare on some Variable type for gatter and setter model.

Can i declare in simple and clean code like in java?

```
private String firstName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
```

Because when converting it to Kotlin it look like:

```
private var firstName: String? = null

fun getfirstName(): String {
    return firstName
}

fun setfirstName(firstName: String) {
    this.firstName = firstName
}
```

What is the right and cleanest way?

Comment: do you generally want to know how vars are defined or just for this one case?

Answer (score 6):

the cleanest way is just define it as a [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) in kotlin, if you don't do additional work on *getter*/*setter* . for example:

```
var firstName: String? = null
```

Comment: `firstName` should be public.

Comment: @Naetmul yeah. I just copy the OP's code. and forget to change the visibility modifier. thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

try following

Synetx:

```
 var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
        [<getter>]
        [<setter>]
```

Examples:

```
var allByDefault: Int? // error: explicit initializer required, default getter and setter implied
var initialized = 1 // has type Int, default getter and setter
```

The full syntax of a read-only property declaration differs from a mutable one in two ways: it starts with `val` instead of var and does not allow a setter:

```
val simple: Int? // has type Int, default getter, must be initialized in constructor
val inferredType = 1 // has type Int and a default getter
```